# How to secure VIDEO files streamed from Windows server machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, video, video-streaming

I develop a video-streaming application. Using a machine with Windows Server I deliver mp4 video files to the application's users. **All the video content is basically public in the Internet**. They are simply mp4 files on a machine, with no security rules in place.

Since I want to introduce a subscription option in my application (the users of the app have to pay to view certain videos), **securing the video content is a must**.

My question is: **how can I authenticate the video streaming?**

Comment: Digital Rights Management (DRM)

Comment: @aergistal could you please elaborate more? Should I use a vendor to be able to use DRM, or I should be able to implement a solution myself?

Comment: it depends on the desired level of security and restrictions, targeted platforms etc. You may want just a minimal token-based authentication system or need to support use-cases like secure offline rental. Take a look at PlayReady, Widevine, FairPlay. If you want a full fledged DRM you should use a vendor since the solution is far more likely to be thoroughly tested against different types of attacks.